# How do I put $db in a central location, but maintain variable scope

Tags: php, pdo

I have that $db, that I will use again and again to connect to the database. How do I put this in a central location so if I change my db I will not have to rewrite a bunch of lines of code? Everything I've tried so far just gives me an error concerning variable scope, the variable is not declared in my functions, so I am forced to simply connect and use the $db object everytime I need to access the database.

TLDR: How do I create the $db object once, and then use it again and again. Just looking for a general idea here.

```
function input_registration ($email, $password) {

$email_clean = htmlspecialchars($email);
$password_clean = htmlspecialchars($password);

$hash = md5($password_clean);

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users", "root", "");

try {

$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT into userinfo(email, hash) VALUES (:email, :hash)");

$array_parameters = array(

    'email' => $email_clean,
    'hash'  => $hash

    );

$statement->execute($array_parameters);

  }

catch (Exception $error) {

    echo "Database error: ". $error->getMessage();
  }

}
```

Comment: The second. Sorry.

Comment: Ah, alright. Have reverted it back to the original formatting except with the markdown fixed a little bit. I suspect someone's review will contain a "use more standard indenting" item, so I wanted to make sure it didn't get silently fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't find the correct answer until your code is just a bunch simple PHP scripts. The ultimate solution would be is to use a dependency injection container and resolver where sou can say for example a PDO instance to keep in use until the request ends (in PHP this would be a singleton behavior).

If you can't rewrite your whole system to have an object oriented design to have the ability to use a DI container then the only thing you could do is to create a class loader in your bootstrap section to load a factory.

A Factory is a simple class which can build object instances like a DatabaseFactory::CreateNewConnection would return a new PDO instance. You can create a static factory but that would be as flexible as the pig-iron. A recommend you to have a static DatabaseBuilder class there you can register a DatabaseFactory class instance as the default database factory and your factory can hold a database class instance until the request ends. Here is the skeleton:

```
<?php

class DatabaseFactoryBuilder {

    private function __construct() {}

    public static function SetFactory(IDatabaseFactory $factory) {
        $this->_factory = $factory;
    }

    public static function GetFactory() {
        return $this->_factory;
    }

}

interface IDatabaseFactory {
    function GetDatabase();
}

class DatabaseFactory implements IDatabaseFactory {

    /* ... */

    private $_db;

    public function __construct($dbServer, $dbName, $dbUser, $dbPassword) {
        /* ... */
    }

    public function GetDatabase() {
        if ($this->_db == NULL) {
            $this->_db = new PDO(/* ... */);
        }

        return $this->_db;
    }

}
```

Ofcourse as you can se you have to create a decent way to set the connection properties for your database.

Answer (score 0):

I'll keep the procedural style, you use; otherwise I'd prefer object oriented code.

You need a function that creates the database connection on the first call and returns that connection on every call.

```
function getDbConnection()
{
    static $db = null;

    if (is_null($db)) {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users", "root", "");
    }
    return $db;
}
```

The `static` keyword makes the variable keep its value after leaving the function.

Now the functions with database access only have to know the `getDbConnection()` function, but no details about the connection.

```
function input_registration($email, $password)
{
    try {
        $db = getDbConnection();
        $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO userinfo(email, hash) VALUES (:email, :hash)");
        $array_parameters = array(
            'email' => $email,
            'hash'  => md5($password)
        );
        $statement->execute($array_parameters);
    } catch (Exception $error) {
        echo "Database error: ". $error->getMessage();
    }
}
```

It is better design though, if any function that needs the database connection, gets it through its arguments.

```
function input_registration(PDO $db, $email, $password)
{
    try {
        $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO userinfo(email, hash) VALUES (:email, :hash)");
        $array_parameters = array(
            'email' => $email,
            'hash'  => md5($password)
        );
        $statement->execute($array_parameters);
    } catch (Exception $error) {
        echo "Database error: ". $error->getMessage();
    }
}
```